# Can a Nostromo macro read the state of the scroll lock button?

Tags: controllers

Can a Nostromo macro "read" the state of the scroll lock button toggle?

I want to change an action when scroll lock is activated. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it cannot.

Macros are recorded key combinations/strokes that are input with a time difference (which you can adjust).

What you could do is add the scroll lock to the start of your macro recording and change your game play a little bit.